# Integrating Azure Function, Service Bus and SignalR

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I'm architecting an application used for team tasks management. The requirement is that every member of a team can add a task, and other members can see those tasks immediately.

The different services that I'm choosing are `Azure Function`, `Azure Service Bus`, `Azure SQL DB` and `SignalR`.

My idea is:

1. User adds a `task` in a Javascript client application in the Browser which will be sent to `Azure Function`.
2. `Azure Function` adds the user to the SQL DB. Sends an event called `TaskAdded` to `Azure Service Bus`.
3. `SignalR` receives the message, generate a new list of tasks and update client browsers in real time.

My question is, what communication/integration protocols (binding, message) should be used to make all the services work together to meet the requirement?

Comment: I think you're looking building similar solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554589/how-to-use-signalr-in-an-azure-function-app

Comment: I have ```Azure Service Bus``` to scale the requests from the users. I don't see that in that question.

Comment: Azure Service Bus won't work as serverless, but you can create hundreds of concurrent connection with single instance. Maybe I didn't understand your exact problem